# What ends the loop in this Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop, break

What ends the loop here?

There is no break , and the condition will still be True

```
def binary_search(list, target):
    '''
    This function will return one of two things:
    1 - index position of the target
    2 - None
    '''
    first = 0
    last = len(list) - 1

    while first <= last:
        middle = (first + last) // 2

        if list[middle] == target:
            return middle # Return the index position of the target
        elif list[middle] < target:
            first = middle + 1
        elif list[middle] > target:
            last = middle - 1

    return None
```

Comment: `return` statement finishes this loop. But only if there exists an element that is equal to `target`.

Comment: Take the effort to step through the code with a debugger, and you will have no more question.

Comment: This is binary search algorithm. It will end because at some point you'll return middle, ending the function, or last will become < to first, breaking the statement.

Comment: Why do you say: `the condition will still be True`? Both `first` and `last` can be modified during the loop, so its possible the `while` might quit.

Answer (score 0):

The `return middle` does, when `list[middle] == target`.

```
def binary_search(list, target):
    first = 0
    last = len(list) - 1

    while first <= last:
        middle = (first + last) // 2

        if list[middle] == target:
            print("stopping...")
            return middle  # Return the index position of the target
        elif list[middle] < target:
            first = middle + 1
        elif list[middle] > target:
            last = middle - 1
    return None


binary_search([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)  # >>> stopping...
```

Answer (score 0):

Return will cancel the function out. This will happen in this case at `return middle`.